# cmd_vel.y=1 stop pioneer robot

Tags: navigation, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone, I'm runing navigation tutorial thoes days, it seems all goes well now, I can mapping, localize and navigate the robot in stage, but there is a prolem, when the robot stucked by some obstacle, it will stop. I use

```
rostopic echo /cmd_vel
```

, and get result as blow:

```
linear: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.1
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
```

What I known is that on Pioneer robot, the cmd_vel.linear.y have no effection on robot's move, but the move_base node just publihsed this value in cmd_vel...

Besides, I have configure the robot according to [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) ,but only use stage as simulator and change the map file.

Any suggestion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35589/cmd_vel.y=1-stop-pioneer-robot/) by [viking](https://answers.ros.org/users/2532/viking/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-06-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you have set holonimic_robot: true in
[RobotSetup#Base_Local_Planner_Configuration](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup#Base_Local_Planner_Configuration)
which isn't true.

If it's not holonomic the local planner shouldn't set y-velocities.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4